# Android slide out fragment animation

Tags: android, android-studio

I am currently making a card game. Basically, I am using fragments to do some animations with the cards. So far I have been able to get the card to flip over from the back of the card to the face of the card. However, once the face of the card is show and the user has seen it. I would like them to be able to press a button and have the face of the card slide off of the deck. I can't figure out how to slide the card off of the deck and have the back of another card shown beneath it.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using ViewPager to show your stack of Cards, you can use the PageTransformer to slide the card out. It's easier if the action is sliding the card rather than a button - But you can get it done your way as well.

Comment: Im not using ViewPager. Just using two fragments and trying to transition between them.